# How do I restrict non-superuser users in Django admin from choosing all user groups/permissions?

Tags: django, django-admin

I was able to disable the form fields but a user can still use `Choose all` to select all the groups or all the permissions. How can I disable/remove `Choose all` for a staff user?

The reason I need this is because I want some of the staffs to be able to change user `Personal Info` but not change `Permissions` or `Important dates` section.

Here is the code that I used so far:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (AccountInline, )

    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form = super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        is_superuser = request.user.is_superuser
        disabled_fields = set()  # type: Set[str]

        # Prevent non-superusers from editing their own permissions
        if not is_superuser:
            disabled_fields |= {
                'username',
                'is_staff',
                'is_superuser',
                'user_permissions',
                'groups',
                'last_login',
                'date_joined',
            }

        for f in disabled_fields:
            if f in form.base_fields:
                form.base_fields[f].disabled = True

        return form
```

Comment: Just a notice first: the django admin is not meant to be used by "regular users", only by powerusers/admins of some sort (superuser or staff). If you really mean "regular users" then you'd better write a dedicated UI for them, it will be easier than trying to fight against django-admin (and will let you present features in a more meaningful way than a mere CRUD).

Comment: Now if by "regular users" you really meant staff users, you might be better providing your own custom modelform instead of trying to hack the autogenerated one.

Comment: You could control the actions of users by assigning appropriate permissions to them through Django Admin. You could set these permissions either on *User level* or *Group Level*. [See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUZoA.png)

Comment: By "regular users" I meant Staff users, I have updated the post. The reason I need this is because I want some of the staffs to be able to change user `Personal Info` but not change `Permissions` or `Important dates` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried redefining `get_fieldsets` in your `UserAdmin`? Something like

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
....
def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        return [(None, {'fields': ('your_editable_fields',)}),]
    else:
        return self.fieldsets
```

A bit modified, it allowed me to leave only certain fields for a superuser form.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is actually a better solution than what I was looking for.

Comment: thanks, got an idea to solve the problem.